# How to stop auto spell in UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I am using `UITextFields` in my project. I have set the following parameters where client doesn't want auto spell:

```
  txt.autocorrectionType=FALSE;
  txt.autocapitalizationType=FALSE;
```

It stops auto capitalization but auto spell is still there.

Can anyone help? How can I stop the auto spell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef enum {
    UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone,
    UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords,
    UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences,
    UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters,
} UITextAutocapitalizationType;


typedef enum {
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes,
} UITextAutocorrectionType;
```

Here FALSE means 0 , where both has

```
     UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone,UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault.
```

that's y autocapitalization is worked, autocorrection is still in as default.so wont work.

So u have to try like this

```
        [urTextField setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];

        [urTextField setAutocapitalizationType:UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits). You want to use `UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
txt.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
txt.autocorrectionType     = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```